# How to people knows the cmd in OS X application?

Tags: macos, terminal

For example, here is some cmd in the terminal that can config the application behavior:
`defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -boolean YES`

How the people know that config? Does Apple have a user manual to tell them? Or is there anyway to know that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like apple doesn't have any manual on that topic. But there are [some enthusiasts](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx) around the world. See this [post](http://mac.appstorm.net/general/app-news/hackers-defaults-for-os-x-released-on-githubs/) for some additional info.